# Is it ok to say "past participants" instead of "past participle"?

Tags: word-usage

**Past participle** : the form of a verb, typically ending in -ed in English, which is used in forming perfect and passive tenses and sometimes as an adjective, e.g. looked in have you looked?, lost in lost property.

If you google "past participants". google propose "past participants of verbs" , is this correct, more generally

*Is it ok to say "past participants"  instead of "past participle"*

Comment: The past participle has plenty of names already.  Different works on grammar refer to it as the "perfect participle" (though I've noticed others use that term for the composite "having -ed" form), "passive participle", "second participle", "-ed participle", "-en participle", "-ed/-en form", and doubtless various other names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are two different words.

Participant means one who participates/participated.

Participle comes from 'particeps (“sharing”), from pars (“part”) + capiō (“take, seize”)' or in other words something which shares the verb.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Past participants" means something completely different.